# Want to vs One two

Tags: pronunciation

When pronounced at normal speech speed, do the words "want to" and "one two" have any difference in the sound they produce?

Comment: *Usually* there will be a "reduced glottal stop" between the two words ***want + to***, whereas ***one + two*** (like ***unto***) has no such "half-gap".

Comment: From [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-the-English-word-to-more-commonly-pronounced-as-tu%CB%90-or-t%C9%99-in-the-western-world): 'There are rare instances where it might be pronounced as it is spelled (depending on the sentence stress/prosody), but in general it is /tə/ . ' "I wan tə go to ..."

Comment: Depends on the speaker, the listener, and the context.

Comment: Also, the 't' of *want* geminates with the 't' of *to*, so it's longer than the single 't' of *one two*.

Comment: @Decapitated Soul The good ol' one-two?

Comment: Maybe they're not exactly the same, but they're close enough for a comedic children's song: 'One "Want to 'One-two-two-two-two-two' too" too many' — [Billy Jonas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a51KEf1OQlI)

Comment: They can be pronounced almost identically, and probly are in some people's speech occasionally. Why?

Comment: Thank you, guys. @JohnLawler A friend wanted to name a software tool he developed using "12" instead of the words "want to" and the question arose whether it would make sense or not.

Comment: Also, "want to" is sometimes sloppily pronounced as "wanna" or "wanta", but "one two" would not be pronounced like that.

Comment: Yes, a great deal depends on how fast one is speaking. And which dialect of English one is speaking in. And which dialect of English one is listening in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many people do not have the same vowel sound in *want* and *one*.

In British English, *want* has the LOT wowel (/wɒnt/), whereas *one* usually has the BUD vowel (/wʌn/).  However, the pronunciation of *one* as /wɒn/ does exist and is gaining ground.  It makes *one* a homophone of *wan*.

J. C. Wells, whose phonetic notation I use, has some statistical information in his *Longman Pronunciation Dictionary* taken from the surveys he conducted.  He gives the distribution of both pronunciations as:

/wʌn/ 70% but above 80% among older speakers,
/wɒn/ 30% but above 40% among younger speakers.

Now to American English and *want*.  The most usual pronunciation of want, according to Wells' LPD, is /wɑ:nt/ with the FATHER vowel, less common are /wɔ:nt/ with the WAR vowel and /wʌnt/ with the BUD vowel.  So there is a case for homophony between *want to* and *one two* in American English too.

However, in "normal" speech in both varieties, *want to* is often reduced to *wanna* (no *t* sounded), and *to* to /tə/, whereas *two* will keep its full, non-reduced sound /tu:/.

To conclude, the chances are *want to* and *one two* won't be pronounced in the same way, at least in the two varieties of English I've described.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you for the clarification.